# Angular Dialog Size

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-dialog in my code where I display a list of elements. But the first column is too narrow for its contents so, the properties of it overlap the row below. How can I make the dialog wider?

```
<mat-dialog-content class="pt-4">
    <div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="material-request-table w-100-p">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                    <div>
                        {{row.Name}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Number">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Number </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
                    <span>{{row.Number}}</span>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns; let i = index"></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  maxWidth: '100%',    
});
```

More in the [MatDialog docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig).